# @OneToMany Map silently deletes Map's keys

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have the follow code that is supposed to save a map to a database. The problem is that while it saves the entities, as well as their relations, it silently discards the maps key values - no error, nothing, the database just gets NULLs instead.

Code:

```
package com.tester;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapKey;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class App {
    @Entity
    @Table (name = "test_items")
    @Data
    @ToString (exclude = "parent")
    public static class Item {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        int slot;

        @ManyToOne
        private Item parent;

        @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
        @MapKey (name = "slot")
        Map<Integer, Item>  children;
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (final Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SessionFactory sf = buildSessionFactory();
        final Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        final Item item100 = new Item();
        final Item item110 = new Item();
        session.save(item100);
        session.save(item110);
        session.flush();
        item110.setParent(item100);
        final HashMap<Integer, Item> children = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
        children.put(3, item110);
        item100.setChildren(children);
        session.saveOrUpdate(item100);
        session.saveOrUpdate(item110);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Expected database result after the above:

```
id  slot parent_id
1   0    NULL
2   3    1 [->]
```

Actual result:

```
id  slot parent_id
1   0    NULL
2   0    1 [->]
```

As you can see, even though Hibernate made a column for the keys, they get populated by NULL, and the information piece '3' from `children.put(3, item110);` is not persisted into the database at all. It is completely lost.

Ideas ?

Note: I have also tried `@MapKeyClass (Integer.class)` but with no success.

Edit: The 3 in question is not meant to refer anything else and is not a reference to any other field/column. It's an arbitrary value which, in this particular context, should define the index of an item in a container with a number of slots. But for all I care, you could replace it with "abcdefg" (assuming you changed the Map to take String instead of Integer, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (sometimes harsh) rule for JPA is that *all* relationships between entities must be *properly* established prior to persistence, if you expect the retrieve the same entities with the same relationships.

So, ask yourself: where did '3' come from, and what is it intended to mean?  Where is it persisted?

### Option: Map Key is not a persisted field

This seems the least likely, but the update to the question states this to be the case.  When you retrieve an entity, it's going to need *something* in the key.  It's not going to just make something up.

Bottom line: you can't use a Map in this case; use a `List<Item>` instead.  You should still be able to access by some index.

### Option: Map Key is a persisted field

If the map key is a persisted field, it must be specified:

```
@MapKey(name=<keyfieldname>)
```

#### Using a field other than `id` as the map key:

For your situation, introduce a new field (you've run out of options with the current example!):

```
@Column
Integer slot;
```

and use the appropriate @MapKey on the Map:

```
@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
@MapKey(name="slot")
Map<Long, Item> children = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
```

and finally in your code:

...

```
final Item parent = new Item();
final Item child = new Item();
child.setSlot(3);
child.setParent(parent);

final HashMap<Integer, Item> children = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
children.put(child.getParentKey(), child);
parent.setChildren(children);

session.save(child);
session.save(parent);
```

#### Using the `id` as the map key:

Using the id (once you get the type's right) introduces a new issue: how to obtain the child's `id` (generated automatically) prior to creating the parent.  Given a JPA `EntityManager em`:

```
@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
@MapKey(name="id")
Map<Long, Item> children = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();

...

final Item parent = new Item();

final Item child = new Item();
child.setParent(parent);
em.persist(child);
em.flush(); // Force child's 'id' to be generated & populated

final HashMap<Integer, Item> children = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
children.put(child.getId(), child);
parent.setChildren(children);

em.persist(parent);
```

This works fine with JPA/EclipseLink, I can only assume it'd work with Hibernate `Session` with methods `save` and `flush`.

Comment: But with Cascade = all, then children need only be added to the parent's container and they will be persisted as well. Conversely, when the child is removed from the parent's container, the child record will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, HOWEVER: the point here is that you simply CANNOT add the child to the parent container, because the child doesn't exist (yet), hence it hasn't been assigned a primary key (the `id` field).  Given the use of the `Map` in the parent to reference children this is problematic.  If a simple `List` had been used, then yes.. you could just link everything up and persist the parent once.

Comment: right, totally skipped over the special container. Why are we using that instead of a list?

Comment: I just typed the 3 in. It does not mean anything in this context, and does not refer to any other column. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: And I updated my response accordingly: if it doesn't "mean anything", get rid of it.  Use `List<Item>`.  I'm actually a bit floored by this response!  If it doesn't mean anything, if it doesn't refer to any column, what exactly *did* you expect JPA to do for you here other than return NULL?!

Comment: Obviously it means something in the context of my application, but not in the context of persisting it. I expected JPA to put the value that I gave it there - the 3. That being said - I came to the same conclusion, trying @MapKey, but no joy. The key is not persisted. I will update my question in a minute with new code.

Comment: Again, see update - you need @MapKey and you need a field for JPA to store the '3'.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your response - are you saying that the map key being ignored and discarded is working as intended ? You have put `children.put(child.getParentKey(), child);`, but in fact, I could put `children.put(1234567, child);` and it would still produce the same data in the database. What, then, is the maps key value even for ?

Comment: I'm saying that until you create a column into which JPA can store the key, then the key will never be persisted in the database, it therefore cannot be extracted with the original value you give it.  Go back and ask yourself: what did you expect to see, other than NULL.  And how exactly is the information that you want to see supposed to be "saved" so it can be "retrieved"?

Comment: Yes, yes, I did that, posted it above, basically the same thing you advised. It works when I manually set the field, but not when I use the map interface.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25899/discussion-between-jorg-stover-and-richard-sitze)

Comment: I *think* we may be back to the first sentence of my answer.  You'll need to manually set 'slot' AND add it to the Map, thereby fully establishing the bi-directional relationship.  As you've noted, you can sometimes not add it to the Map (in this specific case), however JPA won't magically add it to the map in the same persistence context.  It's best to just fill it all out.

Comment: That's what I figured from the later answers, I was not able to grasp that from the original first line. It still seems strange and unintuitive that after I tell Hibernate/JPA that I want column x to hold my key, it can LOAD keys from there, but it won't PUT keys there when I put them in the map. Anyways, I think this answers my question as well as possible, even though it's not what I wanted to hear ;) Thank you.